# windows phone7, I would like to post my data by using PHP page.

Tags: php, windows-phone-7, http-post

My php code is

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    define("__ZBXE__", true);
    include("../../files/config/db.config.php");
    $connect = @mysql_connect(localhost, kah601, kah909090);
    @mysql_select_db("kah601", $connect);
    @mysql_query("set names utf8");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$name = $_POST['ox_score'];
$name = $_POST['between_score'];
$name = $_POST['order_score'];
$name = $_POST['total_score'];


$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO `jp_mango` (`name`, `ox_score`, `between_score`, `order_score`, `total_score` ) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' , '%s');",$name, $ox_score, $between_score, $order_score, $total_score); 



$result = mysql_query($sql, $connect);

mysql_close();

?>
```

I should upload the 5 data (name, ox_score, between_score, order_score, total_score).

And I made this code with reference from stack overflow. 
but I can not post data.
When i see load page, That shows like this. (num is auto-incremented )

```
"num":"8","name":"","ox_score":"","between_score":"","order_score":"","total_score":""
```

How can I post this kind of data?
Please help me out.

```
string sendData = "";
            Uri site = new Uri("http://kah601.cafe24.com/jp_mango_writeboard.php");
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            sendData += "name=hello";
            sendData += "ox_score=10";
            sendData += "between_score=10";
            sendData += "order_score=10";
            sendData += "total_score=30";
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = sendData.Length.ToString();
            wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadStringCompleted);
            //wc.UploadStringAsync(site, "POST", post_name, "name");
            wc.UploadStringAsync(site, "POST", sendData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you will have to modify the string format like this

```
sendData += "name=hello";
sendData += "&ox_score=10";
sendData += "&between_score=10";
sendData += "&order_score=10";
sendData += "&total_score=30";
```

i.e add '&'

Comment: You can upvote answer if it helped you, I think you are new to Stackoverflow!! Also please accept @jhonraymos's answer as it solved your major problem

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. but I can't upvote. because My reputation is just 1. I think I should know how can I up my reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I you have data like this

```
"num":"8","name":"","ox_score":"","between_score":"","order_score":"","total_score":""
```

than you should use

```
  $newdata=json_decode($_POST['data']);

$name=$newdata->name;
$ox_store=$newdara->ox_score;
//and more...
```

Comment: @CindyKim have you got the solution?

Comment: uhm. Not yet. At the first time, I changed my PHP code. $name = $_POST['name']; $ox_score= $_POST['ox_score']; ... like this. but It posts name only. and then I changed the code like yours. ( $name=$newdata->name; $ox_score=$newdara->ox_score; ...) but It posts nothing. I'm a PHP, wp7 beginner.  :-< ........

Comment: @CindyKim you can accept answer by clicking the `right` button under the upvote/downvote button...